Calling APIs via oAuth and fine-grained authorization
I have an external system calling my middleware which then calls Salesforce to retrieve some data. Users login to the external system via an External IDP and retrieve an Access/Refresh Token and an ID token.
An Integration user will be used between Middleware <--> Salesforce but I want to use the scopes provided by IDP to limit what the user can access e.g. UUID to query only their data, scope for Account, Opportunity etc..
My idea is to use the Middleware to extract data from the tokens and then call Salesforce. However, how do I limit/map the scoped retrieved from the IDP to Salesforce to restrict access?

oAuth scopes are not the solution to/for fine-grained authorization (to query only their data). That is done based on the user attached to execution context and the data security model based on that user. Take a look at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security

@identigral But we are currently using an integration user who will need access to everything via profiles/permission sets and top of role hierarchy (as each logged-in user needs access to different objects). Is there no way to restrict access when integrating with Salesforce using this integration user and Scopes from the external IDP?

That's the pro/con of your solution architecture with the integration user. You can use custom oAuth scopes to denote required access at e.g. object level but that'll only work with your custom code.
